# What is a proper way to route an audio from Android device to A2DP device

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm new in android development, I'm developing a simple application that plays a music on button click through speaker , I would like to know how to route an audio to A2DP bluetooth device after paring with the A2DP device.
What are the configurations of AudioManager and other presets?

Thanks!